# How to mark lines on image and save that in MAUI

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui

I have a MAUI application and we have the feedback option in it. User can take or upload the screenshots of the other pages and marks the issues in it. I used community toolkit DrawingView for marking or drawing on the image. I want to mark the each image separately, currently if I draw on one image it is coming for all the images. Because I'm using the Drawingview control above the image view. So how can I draw or marks something on image and save that like instagram feedback feature.

Here is my xaml

```
 <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 RowDefinitions="*,Auto"
                 Padding="10,20">
        <Editor Placeholder="Briefly explain what's the problem."
                AutoSize="TextChanges"
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontSize="14"/>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="0,20"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="End">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="End"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenshotImgs}"
                        FlowDirection="LeftToRight">

                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
                          Margin="0,0,5,0">
                            <Image Source="{Binding screenShot}"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Aspect="AspectFit"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                HeightRequest="150"
                                WidthRequest="100">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ImageEditTapped"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
 
    <ContentView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 x:Name="preview"
                 IsVisible="false"
                 Margin="0,0,0,-20"
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="White">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Padding="5,0,20,0"
           Style="{StaticResource grid_bg}">
                <HorizontalStackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Image Source="nav_close" Margin="5,0"
                          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="CloseScreenShotView"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label Text="Screenshot"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource label_NavigationText}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Done"
               Grid.Column="1"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Style="{StaticResource label_green}">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SavemarksScreenshotView"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Padding="20,0">
                <Image x:Name="fullimg"
                       Grid.Row="0" 
                       HeightRequest="700"
                       WidthRequest="350"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <toolkit:DrawingView x:Name="drawingView" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     LineColor="Red"
                                     DrawingLineCompleted="drawingView_DrawingLineCompleted"
                                     IsMultiLineModeEnabled="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView>
</Grid>
```

Here when user tap on one image from the bindable layout the `ImageEditTapped` event will trigger and bind that particular image in the fullImg.Source and displaying it. And user can draw or mark anything on it. I want to save the marks on that image into the matching image in the   `BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenshotImgs}"`.Currently I'm unable to save it (Figure -2). And also currently if I mark some thing on one image it is coming in all the other images(Figure 1 and Figure 3).
[image]

Comment: I'd guess you would clear the `Lines` collection to reset the `DrawingView`

Comment: and use [screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/screenshot) to capture the marked up image

Comment: I recommend you refer to the Gerald Versluis's [code repo](https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiDrawingViewSample) and his tutorial about DrawingView. You could simply using ```drawingview.Clear()``` or ```drawingview.Lines.Clear()``` to reset.